# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una auto subscripción en Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
Template.adminListUser_sub.helpers
  listusers: ->  Meteor.users.find()

Meteor.publish 'adminUserLimit', (search) -> 
  user = Meteor.users.find({"profile.name": /prueba/})


'click .btn_search': () ->
    search = $('.text_search').val()
    Meteor.subscribe 'adminUserLimit',search, () ->
      console.log "termino la subscripcion"
```

Ese es mi código pero lamentablemente mi colección subscripción  no se actualiza con la subscripción.

¿Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable que hagas una suscripción "dinámica", estás generando una suscripción por cada búsqueda que hagas. Lo recomendable es que te suscribas dentro del evento onCreated y no pases ningun parametro, a menos que este sea una subconjunto dentro de la colección.

```
Template.adminListUser_sub.onCreated( function() { 
   this.subscribe( 'adminUserLimit' )
});

Meteor.publish('adminUserLimit', () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: { "profile.name" : 1 } } ); 
}
```

Lo que sí es recomendable, es que, limites los campos y publiques solo los que necesites.